# Can 'hardly' convey two opposite meanings based on its location in a sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, adverbial-phrases, semantics

Is there a semantic difference between these two sentences?

> I defended the case **quite hardly.**

*vs.*

> I **hardly** defended the case.

For my understanding, these two sentences have an opposite meaning. The first sentence means: 'I vigorously defended the case.' and the second means: 'I did only defend the case very little.'. Most discussions I found on this center around the meaning of 'hardly' itself, but I get the feeling, that it actually means what it says in the first sentence. Maybe because of its position in the sentence?

Comment: In the first sentence, you might be thinking of **hardily** (note the *i* in the word), which means *bravely* or *intrepidly*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second "I hardly defended" is good English and it means only did a little bit of work in defending the case.

The first example is never used. It is bad English. It doesn't mean anything much, in particular, it doesn't mean "I defended hard" or "vigorously" It doesn't mean "I did a lot of work in defending the case."

"Hardly" hasn't meant "with great effort" since the sixteenth century.